# When does it become too many libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I have recently been asked to create a small javascript application, that takes in some data (invoices) and returns some outcomes (eg whether it will be paid?)

To help me with this creation I have used multiple libraries and frameworks, some I have used;

- BackBone JS
- JQuery
- BootStrap

I am now looking at some other plugins I could use? Does a point ever come where I have used too much?  If so, when does this happen?

Many Thanks,
Luke

Comment: I think it's too much only from the point where you code becomes hard to understand. Performance shouldn't be a real problem since js files are only parsed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple libraries being used, you will rarely come across a case where code is being run simultaneously, causing a massive slow down. If there is a slow down of performance, then it's up to the programmer to move some of the processing to the server. If you have multiple levels of encapsulation of code, only then can you have multiple libraries being used simultaneously.

Even if you have many libraries, the only problem that they may cause is the bandwidth used during the transfer.

Please do remember, that you can move some of your business logic to the server. It can make the code:

- Readable
- Scalable
- Structure
- Secure

But, these only come with good programming.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at just the small segment of the code, in my opinion its too many libraries when you face the dilemma of which library to use for a task when multiple libraries can perform the same task.

Also from a performance stand point if all you require are small portions from the libraries like BackboneJS, Jquery and Bootstrap, if you need only small bits of functionality from these you might be able to get other lightweight javascript libraries which give you that portion alone. Or plugins for Jquery etc.

That way you save the amount of data you download from server and gain on performance both on server side and client side (browser).

And as it has always been if the code gets too messy refactor and bring in frameworks or structures to make it more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. In your opinion which of the following two options would be best;

1) Use to many libraries, slowing down the site and make the code difficult to read but relative quick to code?
2) Create your own lean custom code, which serves your purposes perfectly but takes a lot of time and effort.